# MS Word 2010 - footnotes in heading styles showing up in header references when converted to PDF

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010, footnote

Headings in Word that have a footnote in them are resulting in numbers followed by "F" in my headers when I convert to PDF. The headers were created using a styleRef cross-reference. Have tried printing to pdf, save as pdf, and the create pdf from the adobe ribbon. See the image attached. The footnote #2 in the heading style shows up in the header as "1F." This pattern is repeated throughout the document. To add a little flare to the issue, this is not an issue with the file - b/c not all machines in our office result in this issue.

[image]

Comment: Since not all machines in your office do not have the same issue with this same file, what is different about those other systems? Is the same version of Word, being run on all systems? Are all systems using the same version of Adobe, including update level?

Comment: Same versions of Word and most using Acrobat DC. Not sure about update level, but most of our updates are automated by network. Any ideas for settings within Acrobat?

Comment: Where it works properly, are they using Acrobat? If you perform on your machine the same exact procedure as others do on their machine where it works properly, do you still have a problem on your machine?